# For which values of $z$ does the sequence $(e^{nz})$ converges? Where $z$ is a complex number.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> For which values of $z$ does the sequence $(e^{nz})$ converges? Where $z$ is a complex number.

I was able to figure it out for numbers with null imaginary part, but I get troubled when considering the imaginary part. Being $z = a + bi$.

With null imaginary part what we have is:
$$ e^{nz} = e^{n\cdot(a+bi)}  $$
As $b=0$, $$ e^{n\cdot(a+bi)} = e^{na}.$$

It converges if  $a\leq 0$, and diverges if $a <0$.

I could not develop the same argument when $b\neq 0$.

What we have is:
$$ e^{n\cdot(a+bi)} = e^{na}\cdot e^{nbi}$$
Which can be rewritten as:
$$ e^{na} \cdot [\cos (nb) + i\cdot \sin(nb)]$$
At this part I could not go any further. I tried thinking about the second term as being bounded but couldn't quite figure it out if it realy is.
Is this the right track? How can I show that $[\cos (nb) + i\cdot \sin(nb)]$ is bounded?

Comment: Not much difference between the two cases you mention.  Just take the magnitude of $e^{na}e^{nbi}$ for $z=a+bi$.

Comment: @Michael, how exactly should I use the magnitude of the number? Are you saying that if the sequence of the magnitude converges then the sequence of the $e^{nz}$ will also converge?

Comment: @RafaelLima Yes, that's correct. I would suggest looking into absolute convergence.

Comment: I don't know what `sen` is. But if it's the sine function, then it should be `sin`.

Comment: @AsafKaragila. Sorry, sine is called seno in portuguese, I always forget about that.

Comment: @Michael, I looked into that, that implication would be true only when talking about series. But the convergence of the absolute values does not implie the sequence converges.

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ converges then $a_n\to0$.

Comment: @RafaelLima:  For complex numbers $z, w$ we have $|zw| = |z||w|$.  Alternatively, $|z| = \sqrt{Re(z)^2 + Im(z)^2}$ where $z= Re(z) + Im(z)i$. If the magnitudes converge to 0 you know the sequence converges to 0, if the magnitudes diverge to $\infty$ then clearly the sequence does not converge.

Comment: Re " the second term being bounded": If $b$ and $n$ are real then $\cos bn$  and $\sin bn$ are real so $|\cos bn + i \sin bn|=$ $\sqrt {\cos^2 bn +\sin^2bn}\;=1.$

Answer (score 1):

Put $e^z=:w$. Then $$e^{nz}=w^n$$ for all $n\geq0$. The complex sequence $\bigl(w^n\bigr)_{n\geq0}$ converges iff either $|w|<1$ or $w=1$. The first is the case if ${\rm Re}(z)<0$ and the second if   $z=2k\pi i$ for some $k\in{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: thank you. I just could not get why is $z = 2k\pi i$. All I got from $w=1$ was that $\ln e^z = \ln1 \Rightarrow z = 0$.

Comment: Actually, I understand how it works because I tested it. But I'm curious to now how to get to such value for $z$.

Comment: $e^{nz}=$ $e^{Re(nz)}(\cos (Im(nz) +i\sin Im(nz))=$ $e^{nRe(z)}(\cos nIm(z)+i\sin nIm(z)).$.....  Since we have  |$\cos nIm(z)+i\sin nIm(z)|=1,$ convergence of $e^{nz}$ will require that $e^{nRe(z)}$ converges,